# Website not scrolling in Windows Phone

Tags: html, css, scroll, windows-phone, media-queries

I have made a responsive website integrated with nodejs, which works fine on all devices.

But in the Windows Phone IE browser, the webpage is not scrolling down, I don't know what's causing this.

```
/*css*/
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    @-ms-viewport {
        width: 320px;
    }
}

/*js*/
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"));

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```

The responsiveness had some issues on Windows Phone, so I used the above code patches to fix the issue. But the scrolling issue remains, do someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Whats the resolution of windows phone you are testing? 480*800? Are you referring to horizontal scrolling?

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi The resolution is 480 x 800.....

Comment: try adding this CSS -ms-touch-action: auto; touch-action: auto;

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi Ok I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to help reproduce the issue?

Comment: @aravind Sorry I couldn't able to identity the source of it. And the site runs in python and node js. So not able regenerate it as a fiddle

Comment: Ok, can you put up a test link?

Comment: @aravind I try for that. Its a closed environment. Not for allowed external access. anyway i will try to get u a link......

Comment: Try adding overflow: auto, or overflow: scroll to the body. I develop mobile websites too and they work just fine on WP.

Comment: Which version of Windows Phone, 7 or 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **The Fix**

Going off of a [couple](http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html) [of](https://coderwall.com/p/zk_2la) [sources](http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/), it seems the hotfix you have put in actually now causes some devices to render improperly (and was recognized as a bug, so it shouldn't happen in later versions...)

Implementing the following should remove the querks you are experiencing:

```
/*CSS*/
@-webkit-viewport{width:device-width}
@-moz-viewport{width:device-width}
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}
@-o-viewport{width:device-width}
@viewport{width:device-width}

/*Javascript*/
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
        appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```

### **Why is it doing this?**

The main reason why this hotfix is needed is because Windows Phone 8 has the wonderful feature of interpreting device-width as not the manufacturer's optimal viewport width, but the actual resolution size (I believe it is the only mobile platform to do this...). This means the only device to actually render everything perfectly is the Nokia Lumia 920 (their flagship product). All others will have side effects.

Originally, the solution you have is the recommended way to get around this by Microsoft, but, as you've seen, it's a little off the mark. This is because it forces the Browser to determine the width of the screen, not the actual manufacturer again, which in turn can have glitches (as you've seen).

Comment: This solution is not working. At least it is not working in nokia lumia 525.Any more suggestion for this.